# Should I use firebase cloud functions for every http request?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Writing a React Native App that allows users to `Register`, `Login`, `Update Account Info`, `Post (Each post contains a short message with 1500 chars or less and/or up to 9 images)` and `Download Posts`. I can do all these tasks without using cloud functions, but I wonder which approach is better and why?

For example, to `Set user's account info`, I could do something like this in my app:

```
    firebase.database().ref(`users/${uid}`)
                       .set({
                           firstName: 'Stack',
                           lastName: 'Overflow'
                       });
```

Or I could simply write a firebase cloud function and every time I want to set a user's account info, I could do something like this:

```
    const SET_ACCOUNT_URL = 'https://firebase.set_account_url.com';
    axios.post(SET_ACCOUNT_URL, {
        firstName: 'Stack',
        lastName: 'Overflow'
    })
    .then(() => ...Do Something Here...)
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Which approach is better and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot depends on scale here. If you're remaining within the free plan limits, the sky is the limit. If you're working at scale, then you'll be paying for the bandwidth to RTDB as well as the invocations of Functions, which could be superfluous.

It's hard to predict what will be useful without knowing your use case [see XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

As a general rule, you can always add functions later, since they can be triggered from a DB write. So if a write suffices, just do that. Later, you can trigger an event off of that write to take any further actions you need.

If you need to hide proprietary functionality (i.e. trademark algorithms or secured game logic) use a Function. If you know you'll be doing calculations on that data or if it can't be triggered by a DB event, then use a Function.

If it's just going to end up in the Database and the goal is validation or restricting access, write to the DB and use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I did think so but just wanted to make sure. This is very helpful!